# When keep typing without any space in a textarea, the display from the textarea showing in a div will exceed the width of the div?

Tags: css

Why keep typing without any space in a textarea, the output from the textarea shown in a div will exceed the width of the div? But the issue won't happen when typing with spaces.

```js
function grab(){
        var x= document.getElementById("text").value;
         document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = x;

        }
```

```html
 <body>  
 <form>
 <textarea id="text" onKeyUp="grab();" onKeyPress="grab();"></textarea><br>
 </form>
 <div id="replace" style="height: 20px; width: 100px;">1</div><br>
 </body>
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no spacing added between your words, so it `overflows` text outside div no line-break is added, so to solve that you could add CSS `word-wrap` property to break a `long word` and wrap that to next line as soon as it reaches end of div.

> word-wrap -
>
> The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and
>   wrap onto the next line.

```js
function grab() {
  var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = x;
}

var ta = document.querySelector("form > textarea");
ta.addEventListener("keyup", grab);
```

```css
#replace {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="text"></textarea>
  <br>
</form>
<div id="replace">1</div>
<br>
```

Comment: @ycd That's because of a long-word, which you could break using css property.

Comment: Welcome @ycd :-)